# How do I prevent multiple inits of a widget in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Lets say I have a jquery plugin called widget which can be used on multiple elements

e.g. `$('.myClass').widget();`

After the page has loaded I am dynamically adding HTML which contains more elements that have the class `myClass`. If I run the code above again, the previously loaded widgets will get initialized again.

One solution I came up with is to remove the class `myClass` after the widget is initialized.

Another idea is to use `.data()` and store an init flag check if it exists when the plugin loads.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Personally I think loading HTML dynamically makes it hard to separate the UI and backend cleanly. I prefer to just load data dynamically and keep all the UI and it's logic (including HTML creation if necessary) in the HTML page. That tends to solve problems like this.

Comment: If you found my answer below to be helpful, please vote it up and mark it as the answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".myClass-init").widget().removeClass(".myClass-init")`

Add a new class called `myClass-init`

This means you can continue using `myClass` for CSS styling and are using a separate new class merely for functionality.

You could use `data-` attributes but the selectors for those are slower. That's a question of whether you think `data-` attributes are more semantic then an extra `class`

Answer (score 3):

I'd say just add on a new class when it's initialized and use the `not` selector to exclude elements that have that class.

```
//Only will work once per element, no matter how many times you run it.
$('.myClass').not('.initialized').widget().addClass('initialized');
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQueryUI widget framework generates pseudo selectors, so if your widget is named 'myWidget' you may use this line to test if it has been initialized:

```
$("#element").is(":ui-myWidget")
```